# Edit DWG/DXF File using .Net Code ObjectARX API

Tags: api, autocad

1. My research has lead me to believe that the ObjectARX API would not allow me to open a DWG file and change that file in any way in .Net code
2. My understanding is that I would need something like RealDWG to do that.

So two questions:
1. I would like to confirm that this is true, because without the ability to alter a DWG one could argue the ObjectARX might not have much purpose.
2. Is the story any different regarding DXF files?

Thanks
(p.s. what I am wanting to do specifically is import a spreadsheet. that said, if I cant edit a DWG/DXF anyway then those details are not important)

Answer (score 1):

To use ObjectARX, you need an AutoCAD license (full version, not the LT one). There is a .NET version of this API.

If you don't have an AutoCAD license, you can use RealDWG or [Teigha](https://www.opendesign.com/) (please note that there is no free/open source option for DWG).

DXF file format is ASCII text and [documented](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf), so you can edit DXF file with custom code, but depending on what you want to do, this can be complicated and time consuming.